# Google Mobile SDK for Business

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm currently using Google maps API and directions API for getting routes, however there is a limitation upto 2500 requests per day. so while searching for a way, got confused after i came across this link..

[Google Maps Mobile SDK for Business: Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/)

Can anyone please explain the difference between this sdk and google maps API..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the individual SDK such as map, you would require a key. That key is persistent, meaning once you have one, you can keep using that same key in your app manifest, regardless of how many copies of the same app you have.

However, there is a daily limit imposed on how much keys can be requested per day from google to prevent abuse. With that said, I don't think you would have a problem of requesting one. If it is given out for today, just wait till tomorrow and the limit would be refreshed.

As for the Enterprise version, you get more support over the normal version. The main differences is that you get the Business SDK as a static library rather than one using the Google Play Services. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

its basically a software development kit that makes use of the google maps api and helps you in development of apps that use those apis... if request limitation is an issue try other opensource apis like argcis or tomtom etc

Comment: Providing links for the software products you've mentioned would have been good...

Comment: thanks for suggestion but those opensource apis are not so efficient as google's, arcGIS (not argcis) is like GTA map.. :)